# Criando um programa para pegar notícias importantes em um site

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://g1.com.br/'
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                        'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                        'Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}



req = requests.get(url,headers= header)

html = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

colecao = soup.find_all(class_="feed-post-body-title gui-text-title gui-color-primary") #div eh texto


for item in colecao:
    print(item.get_text())
```

O código acima deveria pegar as principais notícias no site http://g1.com.br/
ou seja com a tag:

`<p class="feed-post-body-title gui-text-title gui-color-primary gui-color-hover">`

Infelizmente, ele não está fazendo nada e não retorna erro ("Process finished with exit code 0"). Alguém poderia me ajudar? Testei com python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tua classe não está completa:

```
feed-post-body-title gui-text-title gui-color-primary
```

Deveria ser:

```
feed-post-body-title gui-text-title gui-color-primary gui-color-hover
```

Em BeautifulSoup sempre que tentares encontrar items através de um atributo nunca te esqueças de colocar o valor completo do atributo.

Testado com sucesso em python 2.7 e python 3.5.

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar @RuiLima. Os espaços fazem parte do atributo?

Comment: class_ é com underline mesmo?

Comment: Sim, class_ é com underline e os espaços fazem parte do valor do atributo.

Comment: Obrigado,@RuiLima!